# how to fire a funciton passing this as parameter

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I have my script and I want to get the data from the image attr and pass it to my function

```
<script>

function getsomedata(this){

var comment_id=$(this).attr('data-commentId');
var comment_user=$(this).attr('data-commentUser');
var who_like=$(this).attr('data-whoLike');
var like_num_in_comment=$(this).attr('data-likeNuminComment');

//do something
 })
}
```

```
echo '<img onclick="getsomedata(this)" class="c_like_icon"  title="'.$reply_id.'" data-commentId="'.$reply_id.'" data-commentUser="'.$reply_array['comment_user'].'" data-whoLike="'.$username.'" data-likeNuminComment="'.getcommentdetail($reply_id,'like_num').'" src="img/thumb_icon.png"  height="18" width="18">';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".c_like_icon").click(function(e) {
  getsomedata($(this));
});

function getsomedata(el){

  var comment_id=el.attr('data-commentId');
  var comment_user=el.attr('data-commentUser');
  var who_like=el.attr('data-whoLike');
  var like_num_in_comment=el.attr('data-likeNuminComment');
};
```

And remove `onclick="getsomedata(this)"` from your HTML

Comment: does anyway to allow me use onclick ?

Comment: if you need to use onclick for some reason, include the reason in your question.